How to Playwright write or modify existing env variable at runtime
I am using Playwright with TypeScript and I have my .env file where I have a variable called EMAIL=someemail@email.com. When the test run, I needed it to change the EMAIL value into something that was changed during the runtime of the test. Like EMAIL=newemail@email.com
Is it possible and how can I do that? The officially documentation and Internet only specifies how to read from env variable but not how to actually modify it from within the test itself.

I wouldn't change an env variable. Treat them as constants. I'd just use a plain old variable.

The issue I have is that the variable I need to use is completely outside of the file. Its inside a helper class.

The normal approach is to export the variable and import it into the other file module.

Yes that’s what I need. Any idea how to do it?

export {myVariable} or module.exports = {myVariable}?

Yep module.exports looks like the one. How would I then access that var in my test.spec.ts?

import {myVariable} from "./path/to/exporting/file"; or const {myVariable} = require("./path/to/exporting/file");.

Module '"../fixtures/myFixture"' has no exported member '{My Var}'

Variables can't have spaces in them, make sure the exported name is correct. Please [edit] to share your code.

Its not my var name. It has no spaces. Its my fixture.ts that's the problem. Its not recognising that I am trying to export the var. Where would you normally place the module.export part?

How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?. Again, without seeing your code I can't guess the problem, other than to say make it exactly like you see in my example, or in the linked answer.

This is how to update env variable during your test:
process.env['EMAIL'] = 'ewemail@email.com';

or
process.env.EMAIL = 'newemail@email.com';

This is a node feature. Node docs.
